# HTML - setting text color from a CSS file

Tags: html, css

Very new to web design, sorry for the obvious Q, but I am breaking my head here.

I can't understanding why can I not get the text color from my CSS file..

I tried:

```
<p style = "color:red">bla1</p>

<div class ="colorRed">bla2</div>
```

bla1 is red, but bla2 isn't.

My .css:

```
.colorRed
{
    color : red;
}
```

Comment: have you linked your css file between `<head>`

Comment: :] as i said, very new to this, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css code is correct. Check that you have linked css file in your html code or not.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

or put your css directly into `style` tag as follow

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.colorRed
{
    color : red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="colorRed">bla2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/2bAKd/

Answer (score 1):

`<div class ="colorRed">bla2</div>` should work. Check the path to your css file is correct.